# Finding positive integer triples $(m,n,r)$ with $\frac{mr}{m+n}$ being an integer and $r-n > \frac{mr}{m+n}-1$ and $r\le \max{(m,n)}$

Tags: equation-solving, programming, inequalities

I would like to use Mathematica to find all positive integer triples $(m,n,r)$ satisfying

(1) $\frac{mr}{m+n}$ is an integer;

(2) $r-n > \frac{mr}{m+n}-1$;

(3) $r\le \max{(m,n)}$;

(4) $1\le m < 1000$, $1\le n < 1000$, $1\le r < 1000$, all integers.

The code I use is:

```
   FindInstance[m*r ==(m+n)*s && r-n > m*r/(m+n)-1 && r <= Max[m,n] && 0<m<1000 && 0<n<1000 && 0<r<1000, {m,n,r,s}, Integers]
```

But I got an error that I don't understand

[image]

---

Update: As pointed by azerbajdzan, I should use Max instead of FindMaximum (corrected above for convenience of future reference.) I will still happy to see anyone who could improve the code, making it run faster.

Comment: Use `Max` instead of `FindMaximum`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan thanks! No solution then??

Comment: If empty list was returned then no solution - I have not run the code myself.

Comment: Condition (2) says `r-n>m*r/(m+r)-1` but your code says `r-n>m*r/(m+n)-1`.

Comment: @user293787 Thanks a lot! Problem with my condition

Answer (score 3):

Since `m*r/(m+n) == s`, we replace  `r - n > m*r/(m + n) - 1` with  `r - n > s - 1`

```
Reduce[{m*r == (m + n)*s, r - n > s - 1, 
  r <= Max[m, n], {m, n, r} > 0}, Integers]
```

> `False`.

```
FindInstance[{m*r == (m + n)*s, r - n > s - 1, 
  r <= Max[m, n], {m, n, r} > 0}, {m, n, r, s}, Integers]
```

> `{}`

It means that there are no solution satisfies the conditions.